# Downloading a file in AWS EC2 from a protected server accessed by VPN

Tags: amazon-web-services, networking, amazon-ec2, vpn

I have a file on a server located at let's say: https://example.com/myfolder/file.gz
The domain example.com is protected by inbound rules such that I can only access it by connecting to a VPN.
So on my personal hardware when I try to download the file by using curl -O https://example.com/myfolder/file.gz, it gives me **"Unknown host error"**. However, when I connect to VPN via Cisco AnyConnnect and then hit the curl command, file.gz gets downloaded.

Now what I want is to enable an **AWS EC2** instance to be able to download file.gz by executing curl command. However, when I SSH into my EC2 instance and execute the curl command, it gives me the same "Unknown host error" as expected.

I have searched around VPC, ENI, OpenVPN and other AWS offerings but since I'm a beginner to AWS I didn't quite understand what could be the solution to my problem.

FYI - One way to possibly resolve this issue would be to create an elastic IP and whitelist that in the server that I'm trying to access, (in this case example.com) but I want to create more EC2 instances trying to do the same thing, so it would become tedious to manage.

Comment: Unknown host would indicate that the DNS does not resolve? Should the hostname be publicly resolveable?

Comment: @ChrisWilliams No, the hostname (in this case example.com) access should only be allowed over whitelisted IP provided by VPN. On my physical infrastructure, I can download the file by connecting to VPN. I would like my EC2 instance to do the same. But how to connect to VPN there, is the issue I'm facing